# Upgrade from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.1 caused 403 error

Tags: php, apache, upgrade, php-7, http-status-code-403

I recently upgraded from PHP version 5.4 to PHP 7.1, now my site is showing a 403 error when it was previously working fine.

public_html is 755

my files are 644

apache version is 2.4.6

renamed .htaccess to .htaccess.old

I restarted apache server

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this error

Comment: Have you checked your apache logs for the site? Any errors should show up in there with further information

Comment: You're hosting your website from within `/root`? And then you made your `/root` directory world readable so it would work? It's almost like you *want* things to go wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per e_i_pi's comment, I checked apache error logs, it shows

```
'/root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that "/root/" is executable'
```

I changed root permission to 751 and it worked

Comment: Why not set the DocumentRoot to some place sensible? Like `/var/www/html`